# Read URI from SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I want to read an URI from SharedPreferences previously selected by the user with an ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent.

When I capture the Intent result I save the URI key in SharedPreferences populated with the chosen URI. I restart the application. I try to read the URI key String without sucess. The URI path not exists. Why?

(below the key methods)

```
  public void loadMap(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent()
                .setType("*/*")
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open file"), RQ_LOAD_MAP);
    }

 private String loadKey(String key){
        SharedPreferences saved_values = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        return saved_values.getString(key,null);
    }

private void saveKey(String key,String value){
        SharedPreferences saved_values = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=saved_values.edit();
        editor.putString(key,value);
        editor.commit();
    }

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RQ_LOAD_MAP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                setupTextViews();
                saveKey("json",uri.toString());
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, RQ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the onCreate method I get the error trying to read from the dawn URI.

```
String theuri=loadKey("json");
URI uri=Uri.parse(theuri);
readUri(uri);//ERROR
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try using `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on `ContentResolver` to get long-term access to the content: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: takePersistableUriPermission will not work if I restart the activity. I want to read the persisted URI in the onCreate method.

Comment: "takePersistableUriPermission will not work if I restart the activity" -- what is your evidence for this? `takePersistableUriPermission()` works for multiple activities, multiple processes, and multiple days (assuming the user does not delete the underlying content).

Comment: Sorry, you are agree. I will try. Thank you CommonsWare.